# JSON Data show error when added on ajax call (XP only)

Tags: javascript, php, json, apache, windows-xp

I got error when I add the php script when I add it on the ajax request and the error is in the apache log which is this

### *Win32 Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.*

This error only shows on XP server while is not showing on windows seven.
Kindly help.

Comment: I think files access rights are not managed in the same way in XP and Seven.

Comment: check first if you close the file before trying to pass the reference to the script ...

Comment: Hi Gipsz, what the php trying to access is a shell command which is this "wmic cpu get loadpercentage" via shell exec and then I got an error on the apache accessing the PHP script..